# Call function only when check box is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular.js and I was trying to create an html list with checkboxes, so what I was trying to achieve was to call a javascript function, when a user checks a checkbox.

```
<input id='box' ng-model='" + key + "'  ng-change='graphquery(\"" + key + "\")' class = 'queryNameList css-checkbox' type = 'checkbox' />
```

So here, I have used `ng-change` which basically captures all changes, it calls function `graphquery` on both cases ( checking and unchecking)

Is it possible to specify, condition, like it should only call this function if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.graphquery = function(key){
  if(!$scope[key]){
   //do nothing
   return;
  }

//do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ng-change="!key || graphQuery(key)"
```

If the checkbox is checked then `!key`resolves to `false`, so `graphQuery(key)` is executed.

If the checkbox is unchecked then `!key` resolves to `true`, so anything after `||` is ignored;

Answer (score 0):

Check [this example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.checkbox) from the documentation.

ngModel on a checkbox seems to either be `true` or `false` and that's what gets passed to the function that you specify in `ngChange`. If you want to specify a truth value or a falseness value, you can use the `ngTrueValue` and `ngFlaseValue` directives.

See this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8t7DFxXp3UGXBJIkPz5P?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.graphQuery = function(key) {
      if (key)
        $scope.key = key
    }

    $scope.returnKey = function() {
      return '123'
    }
  }
)
```

And in HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input id='box' ng-model='key' ng-change='graphQuery()' class='queryNameList css-checkbox'
       type='checkbox' ng-true-value="{{returnKey()}}" />

    <pre>Key: {{key}}</pre>
</body>
```

So, what you want to do is check if the value of `key` is `true` or `false` and only execute your code when the value is `true` and you can specify a function in `ng-true-value` to return a string in case of `true`.

Answer (score -4):

```
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('change', function(){ 
if(this.checked === true) runMyFunction();
});
```